# How to set String equal to text in .txt file

Tags: java, string, variables, text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a Java String from the contents of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)

I have a .txt file that I want to save in a String variable.  I imported the file with `File f = new  File("test.txt");`. Now I am trying to put the contents of it in a `String` variable. I can not find a clear explanation for how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When you prepare your question, please pay attention to the possible duplicate box. As it turns out, this is a quite common request.

Comment: Have you ever seen my answer to your other question? If not, see it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13852139/540552

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));

String contents = file.nextLine();

file.close();
```

Of course, if your file has multiple lines you can call `nextLine` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));

try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append("\n");
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    String everything = sb.toString();
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```